# How to Work with SELECT statement in POM-TestNG classes in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am stuck in Basic program where how to write Select Statement in POM Class and another TestNG class is calling that POM Class
  Below is my POM class code :

```
package POM;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class LoginCRM {
    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PassiveIdentityProvidersDropDownList")
    private WebElement dropdown;

    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PassiveSignInButton")
    private WebElement sltbtn;

    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UsernameTextBox")
    private WebElement usrname;

    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PasswordTextBox")
    private WebElement password;

    @FindBy(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SubmitButton")
    private WebElement login_btn;

    public LoginCRM(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void login()
    {
        Select sel = new  Select(dropdown);
        sel.selectByVisibleText("HP Internal STS");

        sltbtn.click();
        usrname.sendKeys("r@gmail.com");
        password.sendKeys("@@@@@@@");
        login_btn.click();
    }

}
```

I am Getting **NullPointerException** at **select statement of login method**
below is TestNG class code

```
 @Test
  public void login() {
      LoginCRM log = new LoginCRM(driver);
      log.login();
  }
```

Below is HTML code

```
<form id="aspnetForm" action="/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fppmss360.ford.qa.ams.hpmsdynamics.com%2f&wctx=rm%3d1%26id%3dd05e86a7-ae60-4d86-af91-c70fe89fb627%26ru%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fppmss360.ford.qa.ams.hpmsdynamics.com%252fdefault.aspx&wct=2015-12-15T16%3a42%3a34Z&wauth=urn%3aoasis%3anames%3atc%3aSAML%3a1.0%3aam%3apassword" method="post" name="aspnetForm">
<div>
<div>
<input type="hidden" value="14" name="__db"/>
<div class="MainArea">
<div class="Header">
<div class="GroupXLargeMargin">
<div class="GroupLargeMargin">
<div class="MainActionContainer">
<div class="GroupXLargeMargin">
<div class="GroupXXLargeMargin">
<select id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PassiveIdentityProvidersDropDownList" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PassiveIdentityProvidersDropDownList">
<option value="http://corp.sts.ford.com/adfs/services/trust">Ford Corp STS</option>
<option value="https://mscrm00b.hpuscrmpoc.com/adfs/services/trust">HP Internal STS</option>
</select>
<div>
</div>
</div>
```

Below is the exception printed in stack trace

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Selenium Workspace\FMC360Automation\testng.xml

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getTagName(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:44)
    at POM.LoginCRM.login(LoginCRM.java:34)
    at Script.LoginMain.login(LoginMain.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:821)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1131)
```

comment if anyone can do needful..! :)

Comment: Could you add NPE stack trace?

Comment: @Rémi stack trace added

Comment: You should remove the pom.xml flag. I don't see any maven pom.xml involved in this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing `WebDriver driver` anywhere. Add `@BeforeTest` method in your `TestNG class` as below. I tried your code with this addition, it is now selecting *HP Internal STS*.

```
public class WebDriverTest  {       
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
     public void setup(){

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("file:///C:/Users/dummyUser/Desktop/select_page.html");

    }
@Test
public void testLogin()
{
     LoginCRM log = new LoginCRM(driver);
     log.login();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add on before test and after test

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup(){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/dummyUser/Desktop/select_page.html");
}

@afterTest
    public void close(){
    driver.quit();
}
```